# Black Color Launcher Icon Android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageicon

[image]

I am having issues while setting up my app's launcher icon from image(PNG). the image is showing as black color as shown in the image. I can't figure out why this is happening. This started occurring when I started using android Studio 2.2 preview. please help.

Comment: Is other images work for you? or it set black background to all images?

Comment: change the background and foreground color by scrolling . It will be below "Trim"

Comment: no all images gives the same effect

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to Android Studio Preview. Preview is beta version and it's not supposed to be used for app development for production. You can download stable version of Android studio and that would allow you to have proper launch image. You can find the Android Studio stable version 2.1.2 here
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/stable

I had similar issue and after some research fix the issue by using stable Android Studio version. - [Android App iCon configuration issue - black & white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099478/android-app-icon-configuration-issue-black-white?noredirect=1#comment63633818_38099478)